# find the best combination from two lists

Tags: python, list, combinations, mean, standard-deviation

I have a two different lists. One holds the values of the **mean** that was calculated from other sublists and another list which holds the **standard deviation**. Is there a way to find the best combination?Meaning to find the highest mean with the lowest standard deviation?
This one is the **list of means**(with maximum 4.0):

```
[3.2577333333333334, 3.5, 3.381622807017544, 3.3605494505494504, 3.5, 3.1649999999999996, 4.0, 3.3724369747899154, 3.404678362573099, 3.4175, 3.5850000000000004, 3.3506896551724132, 3.3122834645669292, 3.125, 3.395, nan, 3.5850000000000004, nan, 3.4945999999999997]
```

This one is the **list of standard deviation** calculated:

```
[0.4258484028644727, 0.0, 0.37176233660557445, 0.4186736320715765, 0.165, 4.440892098500626e-16, 0.0, 0.4039026348822172, 0.38311593614201667, 0.0825, 0.08499999999999996, 0.41627395682935037, 0.40617175486607743, 0.37978612402245554, 0.32033363289488725, nan, 0.08499999999999995, nan, 0.28036590377576226]
```

What I want is to rank all the means based on the standard deviation. To rank them based on the top combinations those two can make.

> For example the mean 3.2577333333333334 with standard deviation
>   0.4258484028644727 is worse than the mean 3.381622807017544 with standard deviation 0.37176233660557445.

The mean list is the average GPA for some courses, that is why I need to rank all of them based on the best combinations.
I do not know if I can do something like this with something that already exists since I am new to this or if I should find my way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
list(zip(*(zip(means, stds)).sort()))
```

Comment: i get this error: AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: actually in python 3 probably it needs to be done like this: sorted(list(zip(*(zip(mean, stdev))))) . Thank you so much! @Igor

Comment: @piggy yes, it was a paren misplaced, see the edit.

Comment: Can I ask you something? If I want to change another list that is connected with them and I want to change the order of that list based on how these 2 lists changed then how can I do it? Should I post another question for it or is it relevant? @Igor Rivin

Comment: @piggy In the floating point context, just using `[means, stds, thirdlist]` instead of `[means, stds]` will do fine.